# Is it correct to view a vector space as the space of finite sequences

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Given an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $K$ and a normalized basis $\left\{\frac{e_n}{\| e_n \|}\right\}$, any $v \in V$ can be written as
$$
v=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ \alpha_i e_i}{\| e_i \|}
$$
where $\alpha \in K$. Now my thinking is that if $\alpha_{n}$ is a sequence of length $n$ then we can add the basis vectors together (for simplicity take $(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ as this basis)
$$
\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{e_i}{\| e_i \|}=(1,\ldots,1,1)
$$
and then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ \alpha_i e_i}{\| e_i \|} = \alpha_n =(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)
$$
so is there any real (i.e. strictly mathematical) difference between vectors and finite length sequences? I assume that this could be generalized to infinite dimensions but I know there are some issues with defining a basis in those cases. Can anyone tell me if I'm thinking correctly?

Comment: Yes. Basically what you'e explaining is that a finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means that from the point of view of linear algebra, it "is" $\mathbb{R}^n$. By the way, you don't need a normalized basis. You don't even need a norm, these are additional structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of finite sequences of length $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with elements from $\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, is already a vector space, when combined with the common operations (component addition and multiplication with an $\alpha \in \mathbb{K}$). This vector space is isomorphic to any other $\mathbb{K}$-vectorspace of dimension $n$.

So what you are looking for are isomorphisms. Two vector spaces are "nearly the same" when they are isomorphic.